# Transformation of differential equation to the Hermite equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation in following form: $\frac {d^2\phi}{dx^2} + \left( ax^2+bx+c \right) \phi = 0$. How can I get the Hermite equation from this? I need to get the first one in the form of the Hermite equation $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-2x\frac{dy}{dx}+2\nu y = 0$. Thank for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a shift of the independent variable $x$, you can get rid of the $b$.  Assuming $a < 0$, a scaling of $x$ can make $a = -1$.  Then
$y = e^{x^2/2} \phi$ should satisfy your second equation with $2\nu = c-1$.

Comment: Let me know where could I be wrong.First of all $ax^2+bx+x = a\left( x+\frac{b}{2a}\right) ^2 - \frac{b^2}{4a}+c$. Then $y=x+\frac{b}{2a}$, $dy=dx$.
It gives $\frac{d^2\phi}{dy^2}+\left( ay^2 - \frac{b^2}{4a}+c\right)\phi=0$.
I think the next step is $z = \sqrt{a} y$, $\frac{d \phi}{dy} = \frac{d \phi}{dz}\frac{d z}{dy} = \sqrt{a}\frac{d \phi}{dz}$, $\frac{d^2 \phi}{dy^2} = \sqrt{a}\frac{d^2\phi}{dz^2}\frac{dz}{dy}=a\frac{d^2\phi}{dz^2}$. But then I got $a\frac{d^2\phi}{dz^2}+\left( z^2 - \frac{b^2}{4a}+c\right)\phi=0$. I think it is not the exactly equation I had to get, isn't it?..

Comment: I haven't made the substitution $y=e^{x^2/2}\phi$ yet because I am not sure I got right intermediate result...

Comment: Your first step is right.  Let me write the result as $\dfrac{d^2 \phi}{dy^2} + (a y^2 + d) \phi = 0$.  Then $z = r y$ makes it $r^2 \dfrac{d^2 \phi}{dz^2} + (a z/r^2 + d) \phi = 0$.  You want to take $r^4 = -a$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have gotten the result!